# How to float an element higer than its preceding sibling?

Tags: css, layout, css-float

Is there anyway to allow a floated element to rise above its immediately preceding sibling element? For instance, take the following markup:

```
<article class="main-article">

  <header class="article-header">
    ...
  </header>

  <section class="article-messages">
    ...
  </section>

  <section class="article-info-box">
    ...
  </section>

  <div class="article-content">
    ...
  </div>

  <aside class="article-sidebar">
    .
  </aside>

  <footer class="article-footer">
    ...
  </footer>

</article>
```

With this CSS:

```
.main-article {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.article-header,
.article-messages,
.article-content,
.article-footer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  clear: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
}
.article-info-box,
.article-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  clear: right;
}
```

This will form two columns, with .article-header, .article-messages, .article-content, and .article-footer all on the left and .article-info-box and .article-sidebar on the right. However, .article-info-box will never rise above the top of .article-messages, even though there's nothing in that space. Likewise, .article-sidebar would never rise above .article content.

Is there any way to get .article-info-box to float all the way up to the top of its container, .main-article, so it aligns with the top of .article-header, with .article-sidebar floating up underneath it?

Note that changing the source order is not an option. Also note that none of these elements can have fixed heights.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your info box is not displaying at the top is because of your  hierarchy. In this case what you want to do is place the info box right after the header, thats because your header is 75% wide and the info box is 25% wide it will fill up the remaining space.
here is the way you should code your HTML for this instance your CSS is fine just get rid of the margin-right:-100% .

```
<head>
<style>
.main-article {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.article-header,
.article-messages,
.article-content,
.article-footer {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 74%;
 clear: left;
}
.article-info-box,
.article-sidebar {
 position: inherit;
 float: right;
 width: 25%;
 clear: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article class="main-article">

<header class="article-header">
 <h1>TEST</h1>
</header>

<section class="article-info-box">
 <h2>right-article-info-box</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ante orci, interdum in est sed, fermentum convallis libero. Curabitur ut dui aliquet, porttitor nibh vitae, ultrices enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam aliquet rutrum tortor, feugiat feugiat nisl lobortis vel. Nulla gravida et massa vel sagittis. Sed congue est et gravida venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula, nunc vitae tristique sollicitudin, augue ligula iaculis tortor, a convallis ipsum erat tincidunt augue.</p>
 </section>

 <section class="article-messages">
   <h2>left-article-messages</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ante orci, interdum in est sed, fermentum convallis libero. Curabitur ut dui aliquet, porttitor nibh vitae, ultrices enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam aliquet rutrum tortor, feugiat feugiat nisl lobortis vel. Nulla gravida et massa vel sagittis. Sed congue est et gravida venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula, nunc vitae tristique sollicitudin, augue ligula iaculis tortor, a convallis ipsum erat tincidunt augue.</p>
 </section>


 <div class="article-content">
  <h2>left-article-content</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ante orci, interdum in est sed, fermentum convallis libero. Curabitur ut dui aliquet, porttitor nibh vitae, ultrices enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam aliquet rutrum tortor, feugiat feugiat nisl lobortis vel. Nulla gravida et massa vel sagittis. Sed congue est et gravida venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula, nunc vitae tristique sollicitudin, augue ligula iaculis tortor, a convallis ipsum erat tincidunt augue.</p>
  </div>

 <aside class="article-sidebar">
   <h2>right-article-sidebar</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ante orci, interdum in est sed, fermentum convallis libero. Curabitur ut dui aliquet, porttitor nibh vitae, ultrices enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam aliquet rutrum tortor, feugiat feugiat nisl lobortis vel. Nulla gravida et massa vel sagittis. Sed congue est et gravida venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula, nunc vitae tristique sollicitudin, augue ligula iaculis tortor, a convallis ipsum erat tincidunt augue.</p>
  </aside>

  <footer class="article-footer">
   <h2>left-article-footer</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ante orci, interdum in est sed, fermentum convallis libero. Curabitur ut dui aliquet, porttitor nibh vitae, ultrices enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam aliquet rutrum tortor, feugiat feugiat nisl lobortis vel. Nulla gravida et massa vel sagittis. Sed congue est et gravida venenatis. Vestibulum vehicula, nunc vitae tristique sollicitudin, augue ligula iaculis tortor, a convallis ipsum erat tincidunt augue.</p>
  </footer>

  </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I said, changing the source order is not an option. It has to be header, messages, info-box, content, sidebar, and footer. This is partly for accessibility reasons and partly because I'm building a responsive design, so this isn't the only layout the markup must support. Besides, I would also have to move the sidebar up in order to make that work. The negative margin is in there because of a grid system I'm using, but you are correct that it is unnecessary in this instance.

Comment: just add another css rule but only for info-box with a negative margin-top.
    .article-info-box {
       margin-top:-80px;
     }

Comment: The basic answer is that, using floats. you can't unless you change the source order which you say you can't. Oh, you can fake it with negative margins or relative positioning but it won't be responsive.

Comment: Negative top margins are also a problem, since .article-header doesn't have a set height. I've played with setting margin-bottom:-100% on .article-header, but then I need some way to push .article-messages down by that same amount in the left column. There may not be an answer to this, but I've wanted to do this on a number of sites now, so I thought it'd be a good challenge for the broader community.